# Reset default CSS from jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, revert

I am using a grid layout (Bootstrapper) to display images of a certain width in rows.

```
<li class="span4"><div id="id" class="thumbnail"><img src="**path**"><img></div></li>
<li class="span12"><div id="id-2" class="thumbnail"><img src="**path**"><img></div></li>
<li class="span3"><div id="id-3" class="thumbnail"><img src="**path**"><img></div></li>
```

I'd like to be able to make an image's width span all columns (class="span12") when a user clicks on the image and to revert the image back to the "hardcoded" class of the image when the user clicks on the image again.

```
if (current_span != 'span12') // If image is not already spanning all columns ("span12")
{
$(this).attr('class','span12'); // Add class to span all columns
}
```

Using the above JS, images are displaying with the correct width after one click.

However, on the second click I'd like to revert back to the "hard-coded" class since not all images have the same class (i.e., some belong to 'span3', others to 'span4' and other to 'span12'.

Is there a way to revert back to the "hardcoded" class from the HTML on the second click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS classes will cascade, so the last one in the queue will overwrite any preceding ones. You should be able to simply toggle the "span12" class on/off with jQuery:

```
$(this).toggleClass('span12');
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however toggleClass is not producing an effect on the image width (span). I do not want to remove the class, I just want to be able to revert back to the "original" hardcoded class from the HTML.

Comment: have you checked if the styles of span12 are active afterwards? you could try using ```column-span:all !important;```

Comment: I get the feeling that changing the class to one of the boot-strap classes is not the way to go, you should create a new CSS class `li.expanded` with `img.expanded` with specific rules and then toggle that class, that way you won't be messing around with the classes that are fundamental to the pages layout.

Comment: I'll create a new CSS class and toggle it. Good idea.

Answer (score 2):

are you requiring a class for that? if the previous answer does not work you can try

```
$(this).css('column-span','all');
```

and to remove it either if you have no locale style attribute

```
$(this).removeAttr( 'style' );
```

or otherwise

```
$(this).css('column-span','');
```